# Hard Drive does not appear in 'places'

Tags: places

My hard drive is mounted but does not appear in 'places' or in 'save as'.

How do I find it to save a file?

See my comment below for result of lsblk. Sorry I can't do a better paste. Samsung drive is mounted but does not appear in 'places' when I do 'save as'.

Comment: Is this the same hard drive you've booted from?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and indicate to which storage volume your question refers? Thanks.

Comment: My apologies for being slow.  How do I cut and paste from Terminal to this query?

Comment: NAME   FSTYPE LABEL   UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                        
├─sda1 vfat           482C-5E60                            /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4           60458131-491a-417f-987e-d7ee97f07234 /
└─sda3 swap           9521ad31-127d-4b8e-baa3-5a0643429b13 [SWAP]
sdb                                                        
└─sdb1 ntfs   SAMSUNG 9EA45B47A45B2157                     /media/stuart/SAMSUNG
sr0

Comment: I want to save a file to the Samsung drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can always type `lsblk` in the terminal to see all drives and where they're mounted.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answer to the OP's actual question...

Comment: Yeah, it was edited.

Comment: The actual question wasn't edited though.  My point still stands.

Answer (score 0):

#### Remount?

Assuming this is not the drive you've booted from, you could find and remount the drive to a location known to you...

We can accomplish such by running:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then find your hard drive relative to its size... After this, you can unmount this drive by running:

```
sudo umount hard_drive_location
```

And finally, you can remount this drive by running:

```
sudo mount hard_drive_location where_to_mount
```

You should replace "hard_drive_location" with the location you found using `fdisk`, and you should also replace the "where_to_mount" with where you want to mount to, something like `/mnt` should be good...